# R plot_ly() 3D add vertical 'pins' between surface and points

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to add vertical lines/pins between the points and the NMDS/NMDS2 surface (the 'bottom' of the 3D plot). This is to help orient the position of the points when viewing the static 3D plot outside of RStudio. I'm trying to generate something like what `scatterplot3d` might produce.

**Example plot from scatterplot 3d. The lines between the points and the lower surface are what I am trying to generate in `plot_ly()`. Data is shown below.

[image]

My sample data:

```
cent1 <- structure(list(MHW = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("before", 
"during", "after"), class = "factor"), region4 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("north", "central", "north islands", 
"south"), class = "factor"), mpa_designation = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("smr", "ref"), class = "factor"), 
    NMDS1 = c(-0.00203871468205806, -0.0163789795067529, 0.0992415884324829, 
    -0.0619337823248111, -0.0521942653829068, 0.0558561061282499
    ), NMDS2 = c(-0.073966852764061, 0.0444855390277828, 0.0971028598153799, 
    -0.0813406436228275, 0.0415761480613053, 0.105811130463746
    ), NMDS3 = c(0.0351953529328383, 0.0317522849669617, 0.00538961231383452, 
    -0.0170206229860022, -0.00442410992911777, -0.0548475894376382
    ), centroid_type = c("smr before", "smr during", "smr after", 
    "ref before", "ref during", "ref after"), shapes = c("circle", 
    "circle", "circle", "triangle", "triangle", "triangle")), row.names = c("smr before", 
"smr during", "smr after", "ref before", "ref during", "ref after"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Plot code

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(cent1, x = ~NMDS1, y = ~NMDS2, z = ~NMDS3, color = ~MHW,
                       colors = c('#44b89d','#f56969','#4c78b5'),
                        symbol = ~mpa_designation,
                        symbols = c(16, 15))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

[image] [image]

This function will iterate through all of the traces, looking for the data. The assumptions:

- marker symbols were designated
- the type is `scatter3d`

I haven't tested this extensively, but it is at least somewhat dynamic.

In this function, you'll see markers and symbols. You'll also see that they are essentially made invisible. Because markers were designated, any attempts to add a line trace will be trumped by Plotly and made into `lines+markers`. Since you have symbols, symbols have to be designated as well.

```
# pin each x, y, z point to the floor
pins <- function(plt) {
  plt <<- plotly_build(plt)
  dfs <- lapply(1:length(plt$x$data), # collect plot data
                function(k) {
                  data.frame(
                    x = plt$x$data[[k]]$x,
                    y = plt$x$data[[k]]$y,
                    z = plt$x$data[[k]]$z,
                    mk = plt$x$data[[k]]$marker$symbol)
                })
  df1 <- do.call(rbind, dfs) %>% as.data.frame()
  mz <- min(df1$z)         # the floor the lines are drawn to
  lapply(1:nrow(df1),
         function(j) {
           df2 <- df1[j, ] # which observation
           plt <<- plt %>% 
             add_trace( # for every point, add a line to the "floor"
               x = rep(df2$x, 2), y = rep(df2$y, 2),
               z = c(df2$z, mz), mode = "lines+markers",
               color = I("black"), symbol = I(df2$mk),
               marker = list(size = .0001),
               line = list(color = 'black'), showlegend = F)
         })
  plt
}
```

To use this function, you can pipe this to the end of the existing figure or call it afterward.

```
fig <- plot_ly(cent1, x = ~NMDS1, y = ~NMDS2, z = ~NMDS3, color = ~MHW,
               colors = c('#44b89d','#f56969','#4c78b5'), 
               type = 'scatter3d', mode = "markers",
               symbol = ~mpa_designation, symbols = c(16, 15))

fig %>% pins()
```